# Проблема с запуском приложения на spring-mvc и spring-security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Приложение использует spring-mvc, spring-data и spring-security на Tomcat 9. При попытке запустить томкат отказывается делать деплой с таким сообщением. :

> Artifact xml-approach:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment.
>   See server log for details. 17-Aug-2017 12:40:02.831 INFO
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web
>   application directory
>   [/Users/pavel/GitHub/server/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26/webapps/manager]
>   17-Aug-2017 12:40:02.894 INFO
>   [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]]
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of
>   web application directory
>   [/Users/pavel/GitHub/server/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26/webapps/manager]
>   has finished in [62] ms
>   /Users/pavel/GitHub/server/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26/bin/catalina.sh
>   stop

Не как не могу победить эту проблему помогите пожалуйста.

Вот мои конфигурации mvc:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.pravvich" />

</beans>
```

Security:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

        <form-login
                login-page="/login.do"
                default-target-url="/auth/menu.do"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error"/>

        <csrf disabled="true" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="provider" />
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <display-name>xml-approach</display-name>

    <!-- Path to spring descriptor -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-mvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Process application servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                classpath:spring-data-context.xml
                classpath:spring-mvc-config.xml
                classpath:spring-security-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

И вот такая структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: лог сервра покажите - это кстати написано в сообщении об ошибке

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman да вот искал искал и что-то лога найти не могу думаю может его и нет может такое быть? по пути указанному в сообщении `.../apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26/webapps/manager` может я ищу не так но все облазил его нигде нет((

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman папка logs пустая.

Comment: собирете war и разверните его в ручную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

была похожая ошибка
проблема была в этой строчке

```html
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
```